# GWT DevMode creates .class file in my source folder

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

When I run `GWT DevMode` a lot of `.class files` are generated next to my `.java files`.

Does anyone know if there is a way to tell `DevMode` to put the compile output in `/build` instead ?

It doesn't seem to be an IDE related issue, because I'm using eclipse and I found the same [issue opened on devnet.jetbrains.com](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5506987;jsessionid=D4D04EDD3F0031E885344DE8A014C1B3).

Comment: How do you configure your devmode? We are using gradle (and maven some months ago) and I've never seen any class file in my src directory.

Comment: I never had this issue, but it's probably project configuration issue. What is the output folder?

Comment: I think the issue is related to my start page, in fact the start page in my project is a jsp that contains some imports, and I noticed that the .class files generated next to my sources are those of the classes imported in this jsp

Comment: @ Guillaume Rebesche, it is a maven project and the build generates the .class in the output folder which is target/classes. What i don't understand is that the Devmode when starting generates .class also (see my comment above)